# В Rails7 не приходят данные по WebSocket от сервера к клиенту через ActionCable из фоновой задачи

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, redis, sidekiq

В проекте используется devise, redis и sidekiq.
Я хочу запускать фоновую задачу, по завершению которой отправить клиенту сигнал на обновление страницы.
В консоли браузера отображается только лог об успешном соединении.
В консоли браузера лог о получение данных не появляется, значит данные не приходят.
В браузере, вр вкладке разработчика, в разделе сетей вижу, что подключение по сокету есть и постоянный ping проходит, но там данные тоже не отображаются.

Почему не приходят данные и в чем может быть ошибка?

Connection

```rb
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    private

    def find_verified_user
      if verified_user = env['warden'].user
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Канал на сервере

```rb
class BuildingConstructionChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    Rails.logger.debug("Subscribing to BuildingConstructionChannel for user #{current_user.id}")
    stream_for current_user
  end

  def unsubscribed
    Rails.logger.debug("Unsubscribed from BuildingConstructionChannel for user #{current_user.id}")
  end
end
```

Подписка к каналу на клиенте

```js
import consumer from "channels/consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("BuildingConstructionChannel", {
    connected() {
        // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
        console.log('Connected to BuildingConstructionChannel');
    },

    disconnected() {
        // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
        console.log('Disconnected from BuildingConstructionChannel');
    },

    received(data) {
        // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
        console.log('Received data:', data);
        // window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

Контроллер где запускается фоновая задача

```rb
class BuildingsController < ApplicationController
  def build
    @building.update(is_under_construction: true, build_time: @building.time_requirement)
    BuildingConstructionJob.perform_async(@building.id, current_user.id)
    redirect_to castle_path(@building.castle), notice: 'Construction of the building has begun'
  end
  # остальной код
end
```

Фоновая задача

```rb
class BuildingConstructionJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(building_id, user_id)
    begin
      user = User.find(user_id)
      building = Building.find(building_id)

      until building.build_time.zero?
        building.build_time -= 10
        building.save

        sleep(10)
      end

      building.update(is_under_construction: false, build_time: 0)
      
      BuildingConstructionChannel.broadcast_to(user, { message: 'Building construction completed' })
    rescue StandardError => e
        Rails.logger.error("Error in BuildingConstructionJob: #{e.message}")
    end
  end
end
```

По логам /log/development.log видно, что соединение устанавливается, пользователь валидируется, контролер функцию выполняет, фоновую задачу запускает, данные по сокету отправялет:

```bash
Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2023-12-14 08:36:28 +0000
Started GET "/cable" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2023-12-14 08:36:28 +0000
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb:12:in `find_verified_user'
Registered connection (Z2lkOi8vZmNzL1VzZXIvNg)
Subscribing to BuildingConstructionChannel for user 6
BuildingConstructionChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
BuildingConstructionChannel is streaming from building_construction:Z2lkOi8vZmNzL1VzZXIvNg

... тут другие логи выполнения контролера и фоновой задачи

[ActionCable] Broadcasting to building_construction:Z2lkOi8vZmNzL1VzZXIvNg: {:message=>"Building construction completed"}
```

Логи sidekiq так же не показывают ошибок, видно, что запускается и успешно завершается:

```bash
2023-12-14T08:36:17.104Z pid=92135 tid=1lmj class=BuildingConstructionJob jid=07b8000b35785ffb1bbfac00 INFO: start
2023-12-14T08:37:17.343Z pid=92135 tid=1lmj class=BuildingConstructionJob jid=07b8000b35785ffb1bbfac00 elapsed=60.239 INFO: done
```